# Revoke access to certain pages using 404

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I have certain urls which i dont want to access by users but unfortunately can't remove them as they are part of my url. For example i have url like this:

example.com/places (want to revoke access to this page)
example.com/places/in/jaipur/  (location is selected)

example.com/places/restaurants/(want to revoke access to this page)
example.com/places/in/jaipur/restaurants/ (location is selected)

In general I want them to 404 if no location is selected.

Just updated the code in htacess but still urls are accessible:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+places(/restaurants/)?[?\s]  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` file you can do the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/places/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/places/restaurants/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+places(/restaurants/)?[?\s]  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Dont know but urls are still accessible.

Comment: What is an example of full URL that is still accessible?

Comment: Also this needs to be placed as first rule just below `RewriteBase /` line.